# C code returning different result in Delphi?

Tags: c, delphi

I have this C code:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

uint32_t xor160()
{
   static uint32_t x = 123456789, 
   y = 362436069, z = 521288629,
   w = 88675123, v = 5783321;
   uint32_t t = (x^(x<<2)); x = y; y = z; z = w; w = v; 
   return v = (v^(v>>4))^(t^(t>>1));
 }

 int main(void)
  {
     size_t i;
    printf("Xorshift160:");

    for(i=0; i<10; ++i) 
  {
    printf("  %"PRIu32, xor160());
  }
   printf("\n\n");
   return 0;
 }
```

**Result**:

> 393427209  1947109840  565829276  1006220149  971147905  1436324242
>    2800460115  1484058076  3823330032  1552000024

When I converted it to Delphi, it gave me different result, starting from `i = 6` to the end.

```
  type
  TForm1= class(TForm)
   lst1: TListBox;
   function xor160() : UInt64;
 public
    { Public declarations }
      x, y, z, v, w : UInt64;
 end;
function TForm_Improved.xor160() : UInt64;
var
t: UInt64;
begin

t := (x xor (x shl 2));
x := y;    y := z;    z := w;    w := v;
v := (v xor (v shr 4)) xor (t xor (t shr 1));
Result := v;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
i : Integer;
 begin
 x := 123456789;
 y := 362436069;
 z := 521288629;
 w := 88675123;
 v := 5783321;
 for i := 0 to 10 do
   lst1.Items.Add(UIntToStr( xor160() ) );
 end;
```

**Result**:

> 393427209  1947109840  565829276  1006220149  971147905  1436324242
>   4947943763 7523855836 5945647856 7601759256 1532068462

Comment: Well for a start, the Delphi code is using unsigned 64 bit integers where the C is using 32 bit unsigned

Comment: I suggest that you debug this. Find the first operation where the two programs diverge. Then look closely at the operands. Then make two simple programs that just perform the operations that have different results. Now you've isolated the problem and it should be routine to work out what the issue is. In short, take this opportunity to learn to debug.

Comment: Also, your Delphi code does one more iteration step than the C code. C code goes from 0 to 9 (because `i<10`) but Delphi goes from 0 to 10. Hence, Delphi code returns an additional result value.

Comment: The problem has been solved by changing the type from uInt64 to uInt. Thanks @mathematician1975

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the problem is that the C code performs 32 bit arithmetic, but your Delphi code performs 64 bit arithmetic.

This program produces identical output to your C program:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var
  x: Cardinal = 123456789;
  y: Cardinal = 362436069;
  z: Cardinal = 521288629;
  w: Cardinal = 88675123;
  v: Cardinal = 5783321;

function xor160: Cardinal;
var
  t: Cardinal;
begin
  t := x xor (x shl 2);
  x := y;
  y := z;
  z := w;
  w := v;
  v := (v xor (v shr 4)) xor (t xor (t shr 1));
  Result := v;
end;

procedure Main;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Writeln('Xorshift160:');
  for i := 0 to 9 do
    Writeln(xor160);
end;

begin
  Main;
  Readln;
end.
```